# vim mouse mode disable on .vimrc

Tags: linux, vim

If I set `:set mouse-=a` to `.vimrc`, the highlight color will not be seen when I open the file with vim.

how can I set `:set mouse-=a` automatically when I use the vim editor with the previous feature(color, etc.)?

Comment: It looks like there is some confusion, here. What, *exactly*, are you trying to do? Disable the mouse or enable it? Also, what "highlight color" are you talking about? Are you sure `:help 'mouse'` is what you actually need?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in `.vimrc` is `set mouse=a`.

You only use a preceding colon when you are using the command pallet accesed by pressing escape key.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in `.vimrc` to enable your mouse's usage is the following:

```
set mouse=a
```

It appears, according to your question, that you have added a hyphen character(-) before the equals sign, making it `-=`, when it should just be an equals sign (`=`).

Could you please make sure to remove the hyphen and see if it works after that?

Comment: It's `.vimrc` (Unix-like) or `_vimrc` (Windows), not `/vimrc`.

Comment: Totally right, my bad, I misstyped the slash as it is next to the point. Already edited it, thanks